# Mongoose and field types - Number returns object, String returns string?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node.js, mongoose

Say you define a Mongoose schema like so

```
aSchema = new Schema
  count: Number
  text: String

A = mongoose.model "A", aSchema

db = mongoose.connect "mongodb://localhost/test"
a = new A
a.count = 99
a.text = "foo"

a.save (err) ->
  A.findById a, (err, a) ->
    console.log typeof a.text, typeof a.count  #prints string, object
```

Fields of type String behave as expected. But Number fields come back as objects, which means they need to be typecast before being used in comparisons etc.

Why do fields of type Number need casting but not fields of type String?

Answer (score 1):

From one of the authors: https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/338#issuecomment-1092330